# Unpair apple remote from Apple TV

Tags: macbook-pro, appletv, remote-control

I want to un-pair the silver remote that came with the Apple TV (3rd Gen) so that I can use it exclusively with my Macbook Pro. Is there a way to do that? Please help.
Note: I have tried using those instructions from Apple, but the Apple TV remote still continues to control the Apple TV.

Answer (score 2):

Pair is actually a bit of a misnomer.   Unpaired remotes will still control the device.   Pairing only changes the receiver so that it just looks for the paired remote.  In "un -Paired" any remote can control the device.

If you have multiple devices that you do not want to interfere with each other pair them to their own remotes and they will not interfere.   If one device is left unpaired it will still follow signals from other remote.

Comment: I have the Apple TV paired to a 3rd Party remote. I want to use the Apple remote just for my Macbook Pro. But it still wants to control the Apple TV, even after I unpaired it.

Answer (score 1):

*From http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1555*

> **To unpair your Apple TV from a remote**
>
> You can use any Apple Remote to unpair Apple TV from a remote. **Note**: If you lose the Apple Remote that you paired with Apple TV, a replacement remote will not work until you unpair Apple TV from the lost remote.
>
> Press and hold the Menu and Previous/Rewind buttons on a white Apple Remote for 6 seconds, or the Menu and Left buttons on an aluminum Apple Remote for 6 seconds.
>
> You can also use these steps:
>
> 1. Choose **Settings** > **General** > **Remotes** from the Apple TV main menu.
> 2. Choose **Unpair Apple Remote**.
>
> When you’ve successfully unpaired a remote, Apple TV displays a broken chainlink symbol ([image]) above a picture of a remote. You can now pair Apple TV with a different remote.

Comment: I have tried using those instructions from Apple, but the Apple TV remote still continues to control the Apple TV.